# How to get Assembly from a Type object in UWP (aka .NET Core)

Tags: c#, reflection, uwp, .net-core

The Type class has got an Assembly attribute in .NET Framework. However this attribute is gone when you are writing an UWP which is of course using .NET Core. Only the AssemblyQualifiedName attribute is available.

How can I get to the Assembly from this name?

Please bear in mind that lot of the usual classes are not available in .NET Core, so your usual .NET Framework answer might not work. E.g. there is no such thing as AppDomain, etc.

Answer (score 46):

You can use `typeof(xxx).GetTypeInfo().Assembly` to get Assembly。

Comment: Do not forget to add "using System.Reflection;" to your code as GetTypeInfo() is an extension method.

Answer (score 18):

Ok I have overlooked the TypeInfo class that is available using GetTypeInfo on a Type object. TypeInfo has got the Assembly property.

Comment: Mark it as answer please