# Source of MediaElement

Tags: c#, xamarin, win-universal-app

I am trying to play a sound file when I click on a button. The file is located in the Assets folder and the build action is set to content. I tried the following:

Option 1:

```
element.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/alarm.wav");
```

Option 2:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync("alarm.wav");
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
element.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
```

The second option works, but it takes a long time before the sound plays when I click on the button. According to other questions the first option should work, but the sound is not played and there is no exception.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I am using a Xamarin template for cross-platform development. So I have the following structure:

- App (PCL)
- App.Droid
- App.iOS
- App.UWP
- App.WinPhone

With DependencyService I try to play sound on each platform, but with App.UWP option 1 doesn't work.

Comment: I tested the option1 with .wav media file and button click event, it works fine by my side.

Comment: I added the project structure to the question. Is the path/scheme I am using for the URI not right?

Comment: I'not familiar with Xamarin, but the path in your option 2 looks like is same with the path in option 1 in my view. Are you sure your file is in the Assets folder of your App.UWP project?

Comment: Yes, I checked. Also option 2 wouldn't work if that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```
 Uri uri = new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Assets/alarm.wav");
                var player = new MediaPlayer();
                player.Open(uri);
                player.Play();
```

Comment: AppDomain could not be found. What reference do I need?

Comment: it will be in System namespace

Comment: I have `using System` but it still cannot be found. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31987252/how-to-get-assembly-from-a-type-object-in-uwp-aka-net-core) question, it's not possible on UWP since it uses .NETCore

Comment: Oh Okay.. I did not know about .Net Core specifications. While trying the first option , did you add the audio file to the app packages?

Comment: How can I check that? It's in the Assets folder and the build action is Content.